# AMD Laptop Dual Graphics

Tags: graphics-card, amd-radeon, lenovo-laptop, amd-graphics-card, dual-gpu

I bought a Lenovo z50-70 laptop with an amd fx - 7500 processor and a amd r7 1GB APU graphics card and a amd R7 m265 dx 2GB dedicated graphics card. Due to reasons unbeknown to me, I can't change the settings so that just the dedicated card is used when gaming. I can only manage crossfire with the APU (which is very hit and miss depending on the game) or just using the APU. Everything is in max performance mode. I can't seem to get anywhere near the performance of a test on a YouTube channel. He gets 30fps on witcher 2 on ultra 1080p, I can't even get that on lowest settings at 720p! I don't understand. I've looked in the BIOS and the only options I have are "Dual Graphics" or "UMA Only". I'm stuck for ideas. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

1. In the Bios Settings choose Switchable Graphics.
2. Download AMD Overdrive and Disable Turbo Core Menu, less 2.1 GHz max...
3. Open AMD Catalyst, or Crimson (Crimson not recommended install)
   ... and Disable Dual Graphics.
4. Open Switchable Graphics, and browse any games or 3D high performance apps and click High Performance Tab (only all games your system).

any games .. Crysis 3 is in my notebook FX-7500 (Turbo Core is OFF - 2.1 GHz) R7 M265DX (2 GB), integrated R7 Graph. and 8GB System Memory less 1024 MB integrated Graph.. Core 720 MHz - IGP Tuning & 800 MHz memory, and the dedicated VGA is only 855 MHz core and 900 MHz Memory - no Overclocking.. is 1280 x 720 - in 30-35 FPS, then High Texture Options and Low Game effects.. but there is beautiful to, CryEngine awesome textures and graphics engines...
So.. any games 768P, or 720P... and sometimes 1080p low textures is running!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following:

- Keep "Dual Graphics" in BIOS as this will enable both GPUs, the UMA only is iGPU/APU only graphics.
- Download the latest graphics drivers for your laptop from source (amd.com).
- Go to AMD Radeon Settings and set your game to work in High Performance.
- Keep all other settings in Default.
- You may test your game in "High performance" under Windows Power options and see if you gain any noticeable fps.
- Open Wattman/Overdrive and increase your CPU freq. higher but don't go overboard with it as this may damage your laptop.